# How to add hyperlink to GitHub issue as committed comment using C#

Tags: c#, github

I want to add Google Drive document hyperlink to GitHub issue as committed comment. After clicking the hyperlink on the comment, the google doc will be opened. Could anyone tell me how can I do that please?

```
using Octokit;
var gitHubClient = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("AppName"));
gitHubClient.Credentials = new Credentials("Personal_Access_Token");

string userIssueTitle = "Add Google Document link to this issue";
string userIssue = "<H3>This is a new issue</H3>";

var (owner, reposName) = ("myGitHubName", "myRepo");
var newIssue = new NewIssue(userIssueTitle) {Body = userIssue};
newIssue.Assignees.Add("ABC");
newIssue.Milestone = 1;
newIssue.Labels.Add("Bug");
newIssue.Labels.Add("Functional");

var issue = await gitHubClient.Issue.Create(owner, reposName, newIssue);
var issueId = issue.Id;
Console.WriteLine($"SUCCESS: your issue id is {issueId} ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use githubs autolink feature.

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/configuring-autolinks-to-reference-external-resources

Actually it seems like AutoLinks dont work with _ in the identifier, but you should just be able to put in the url and github will convert it to a link automatically.

If you need to create it as a comment, see my reply below.

Comment: The autolink is linked GitHub issue or request to external third party. My situation is another way around. I am trying to import issue and attachments to GitHub issue. Therefore, I wrote the C# code to generate issue on GitHub. And, I want to add the Google Drive Document link as committed comment.

Comment: Please explain about link as per stackoverflow guildlines

Comment: Ah so you basically just want to add a comment to the issue you have just created ? Or do you want to add the link in the description ?

Looks like you are working with Octokit library? I dont think that supports comments, but you can just use the github rest api

You can find the documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/comments